# Some Kivy apps not running in Raspberry Pi - Python

Tags: raspbian, python

Currently, I have a Raspberry Pi 1 Rev2 model B and a Raspberry Pi 3, I'm developing an app that could check dynamic values from several screens, I'm using a 7inch LCD Screen to look the graphics generated from the kivy app.

The problem is that when I test codes that I could use to my code, they are tested in windows 10 and works great, however, when I pasted this code inside the Raspberry Pi and run it, the screen goes black and I can see nothing more, also the touchscreen doesn't work in the kivy app (It works ok outside of the kivy app).

I started to think that was something related to the kivy versions, so I check them:

Windows 10 kivy version: 1.10.0
Raspberry Pi kivy version: 1.10.1.dev0 (I don't know what's the meaning of dev0)

So I use the line code:
import kivy
kivy.requires('1.10.0')

Without any good results, I will paste code from another thread from here in StackOverflow, however, I missed the link so forgive me that:

This is only a code that I wanted to test to use the same logic for my purposes, it will change the label text dynamically.

**YourApp.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import random

class YourWidget(Widget):
    random_number = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(YourWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.random_number = str(random.randint(1, 100))

    def change_text(self):
        self.random_number = str(random.randint(1, 100))

class YourApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return YourWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    YourApp().run()
```

**YourApp.kv**

```
<YourWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Change text"
            on_release: root.change_text()
        Label:
            id: label1
            text: root.random_number
```

Let me know what ideas you have to help with this, it's really annoying that I can't keep going to this kind of problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and the problem was that kivy has a stricter naming convention for the kv file in linux than windows from what I think.

Try renaiming your kv to `Your.kv` and `your.kv`

If this does not help explicitly load your kv file with

```
Builder.load_file('path/to/file.kv')
```

or use

```
Builder.load_string("""
... """")
```

Maybe you can also upload the log file you get when starting kv

Answer (score -2):

Change your .py to Your.py and .kv to   Your.kv and the name before App must be same as kv file name(Case sensitive).

Comment: Why does should it help? We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed or you risk to get down votes. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: He named his app name as YourApp(App) in his python code in order to bind his kv file to his py file

Comment: Please can you elaborate it in your answer? You can edit it. And yes, it is really a good idea for you to take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) :-)

Comment: he Built an App class YourApp(App) so it will try to bind a kv file named Your.kv (whatever written before App) its case sensitive too

Comment: I think you are right as the comments BUT please change the answer's body and add more explanation & clarification.